# 'bsondump --pretty --type=debug' use case and output explanation

Tags: mongodb, json, mongodb-3.2

sample output with type debug

```
bsondump --pretty --type=debug audit.bson.2017-03-10T10-38-23
--- new object ---
        size : 236
                atype
                        type:    2 size: 28
                ts
                        type:    9 size: 12
                local
                        type:    3 size: 37
                        --- new object ---
                                size : 30
                                        ip
                                                type:    2 size: 15
                                        port
                                                type:   16 size: 10
                remote
                        type:    3 size: 38
                        --- new object ---
                                size : 30
                                        ip
                                                type:    2 size: 15
                                        port
                                                type:   16 size: 10
                users
                        type:    4 size: 53
                        --- new object ---
                                size : 46
                                        0
                                                type:    3 size: 41
                                                --- new object ---
                                                        size : 38
                                                                user
                                                                        type:    2 size: 19
                                                                db
                                                                        type:    2 size: 14
                roles
                        type:    4 size: 12
                        --- new object ---
                                size : 5
                param
                        type:    3 size: 39
                        --- new object ---
                                size : 32
                                        ns
                                                type:    2 size: 27
                result
                        type:   16 size: 12
--- new object ---
```

What's `--- new object ---`? It seems not to be a JSON document.
What's `type` and the number? Is `size` characters or other measurement?

Why this output is useful? What's the usecase for DBA or App developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bsondump` utility converts BSON data (which is binary) into human-readable formats. Common usage would be `bsondump --pretty` to inspect data formatted as [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). This can be useful for previewing data contained in BSON files as created by `mongodump`, [replica set rollbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/), and other features (eg. [auditing in MongoDB Enterprise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/#output-to-bson-file) as per your example).

The `--type=debug` output is generally only relevant for a developer who wants to see an annotated view of the BSON (as per the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/)).

> What's `--- new object ---`? It seems not to be a JSON document.

This indicates the start of a new BSON object, which would be represented as an opening curly brace ( `{` ) in JSON. You will see this at the top level for each new document and for every embedded document/array.

> What's `type` and the number? Is `size` characters or other measurement?

This indicates the BSON type and size (in bytes) of that object including nested fields/objects.

Potential use cases for confirming underlying data types might be checking for consistency (eg. a given field has the expected type) or  confirming underlying data types in order to do a query using the  [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator in MongoDB.

You can perform a similar size calculation for a document/object in the `mongo` shell using [`Object.bsonsize(object)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous).